# Brachistochrone Curve trigonometric subsitution

Tags: integration, substitution, trigonometric-integrals, euler-lagrange-equation

Hi I am currently trying to understand the Brachistrone Problem. I was looking at this video: https://youtu.be/zYOAUG8PxyM and at 7:53, there is a substitution for $y= h-C1*\sin^2(\theta/2)$. If someone could please explain how and why the creator substituted this and maybe where this trigonometric substitution comes from. Thank you so much:)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto)

Comment: Put dollar signs before and after any equations you write to make them appear in the right way.

Comment: The author knows that this substitution will work, probably form an educated guess. It gets a little clearer if one writes $h-y=c_1\sin^2\frac\theta2$, making the radical simpler.

Comment: Commands in latex are written with \ beforehand. In your case, the sine function and the greek letter theta should be proceeded by \ to get $\sin$ and $\theta$.